# 301 redirection in the htaccess file, url with "question mark"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to make a single 301 redirection in the htaccess file, where the url to redirect has got a question mark

**old** url to redirect :

- http://www.example.net/index.html?target=page_100.html

to be redirected to the **new following url :

- http://www.example.net/new.html

Could anyone give me the line to add in the htacess file ?

Thank you in advance for any reply.

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html\?target=page_100.\html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /new.html? [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect the request

- /index.html?target=page_100.html

to

- /new.html

The **?** at the end of the rule's target is important to discard the old query strings from new url.